# СПП с придаточным места?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

*Он напрягся и уже безо всякого чувства покаяния и боли вспомнил утопшего связиста и направился туда, где бабочками-капустницами трепетали серенькие чайки-корольки*.

СПП расчлененной структуры. Придаточное места (союзное слово ГДЕ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вид определен верно. Связующий элемент тоже верно определили.